# Quotation and Citation

Tags: american-english, quotations, citation, plagiarism

I have a sentence directly copied from a source to a paper. This sentence is cited but not quoted. In this point, it is regarded as `plagiarism`.

Can we say plagiarism for the opposite case: `Directly copied sentence is quoted but not cited`

Answer (score -2):

Plagiarism is a wrongful appropriation of content from another author. Note that it requires two conditions and both of them require judgement.

1. Appropriation. Copying, or quoting, without citation can be considered appropriation, but not always. It could just be imitation if no implication is made that the copier is attributing the content to themselves. Think of well known phrases, a slogan, a well known theorem. In those examples it is clear that if one reproduces them, then one is not implying ownership of the idea. Suppose that you include *Veni, vidi, vici!* in your text. It is clear for most, who is it that you are citing. It is also clear that you are not claiming being the first using that idea.
2. Wrongful. The appropriation must be judged to be not allowed. If you start a tale with - *Once upon a time, in a faraway country, there lived a princess* - you are likely to be copying many other authors but it should be okay, since lots of people have used it for far long to be illegal.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with either of your two conditions. Without citation the assumption of a reader would be that the words were the author's own. Also the appropriation need not be illegal in order to be wrongful. If I copy a fellow student's essay, and he lets me do it, it wouldn't be illegal but it would be plagiarism.

Comment: @KillingTime That is your assumption, but that is not correct. If I say that the sides of a triangle with a right angle satisfy a^2+b^2=c^2, where c is the length of the side opposite to the right angle, then those are my words, but no one would imply that by quoting without mention or citation Pythagoras' theorem, that I am appropriating the statement. As I said, there is a judgement involved. A judgement will depend on the nature of the quote and also on who judges.